# What I am doing wrong with this bash variable?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I insert a variable into a command?
In the case below, I need to concatenate the command with the variable file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a timestamp function
timestamp() {
  date +"%D-%T" | tr :/ -
}

# Define the file name
value=$(timestamp)
filename= "/home/pi/media/$value.h264"

#Recording
raspivid -w 800 -h 600 -t 15000 -o $filename -n -rot 270

#Terminate the script
exit
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? What makes you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why first assign the `timestamp` to `value`? You can just do:

```
filename="/home/pi/media/"$(timestamp)".h264"
```

And you should quote the filename in the recording command (in case there are spaces in the path, etc.):

```
#Recording
raspivid -w 800 -h 600 -t 15000 -o "$filename" -n -rot 270
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a space after `filename=`  Remove the space and you will be good.